# Function reading in a folder of files returning "Error in file(con, "r"): cannot open conection..."

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a folder of files into R. The following code works for one folder that contains the same type of files, but will not work for another folder. The type of data is the same (both debian files formatted in the same way, just containing different subject's data).

The following code allows me to read all the files (named subject1-subject10) in the "Data1" folder and put it into a list named Data:

```
files <- as.character(list.files(path="/Users/wendy/Box Sync/Data1"))
data <- list() 
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  data[[i]] <- readLines(files[[i]])
}
```

But the following code does not work - this folder (Data2) contains subject11 - subject50:

```
files <- as.character(list.files(path="/Users/wendy/Box Sync/Data2"))
data <- list() 
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  data[[i]] <- readLines(files[[i]])
}
```

This brings up the following message:

**Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'subject11': No such file or directory**

I'm confused, because both folders, containing their respective subject data are in the same file path, except for the last folder name in the path.

The second folder (Data2) differs only in the following ways:

- Number of files in the folder
- contains different subjects
- There is more data (more variables) recorded in "Data2" (e.g. recording age, height, race in Data 2 versus only recording age and height in Data1)

If I were to put some of Data2's files into the Data1 folder and run the top code again, it will produce the same error message as when I run the second code chunk.

Comment: In the second case, what is the output of `files`? Also, you don't need `as.character`, since `list.files()` already returns an object of class `character`.

Comment: The second case outputs a list of the files names (the same as the first case): "Subject11" "Subject12" "Subject13", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `full.names` option.

```
list.files(path="/Users/wendy/Box Sync/Data2", full.names = TRUE)
```

Without it, it only outputs the name of the files, and thus it works only if files with that exact file name are found in the current working directory.